# How to pass callback as a prop to lower components in React without creating a new callback each time?

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-props

I am coming form angular and getting used to react. I was reading the docs on event handling and stumbled upon this:

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

the docs then say:

"
*The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.*"

I don't have access to constructor as I am using hooks. What should I do?

I prepared a quick [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-props-callback-demo?file=src/App.js). The structure is App > [CompA > Comp B]. There is a button in component B that increments count and the state of the count is kept in App. Through props the callback is delegated from App through Comp A to comp B. Whenever I click the count button in Comp B, it re-renders the entire Comp A. This can be verified by the random number generation. It's fine for this component but wouldn't this be a problem in a large project?

Now imagine I have a quiz app and I keep score in the main App. If someone selects right answer inside a Question component I would like to keep a count of that in the main App. Doing it this way would re-render any intermediate components. What's the pattern I should follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `useCallback` hook. It'll return the same function as long as its dependencies remain the same.

`const callback = useCallback(()=> { /* do something */ }, [/* dependencies */])`

The dependencies work the same as the `useEffect` hook.

### Edit

From your demo, `<CompA onCount={() => setCount(count + 1)} />` is perfectly fine, Dan Abramov said as much.

Parent re-renders will render their children, so if the count state is in the parent, the children will be re-rendered. That's perfectly fine. React is built to do that very quickly.

Comment: so the dependency in this case would be count? but then count changes, doesn't it?

Comment: @Grepsoft useCallback isn't necessary for you, it just answers the question on how to not create a new callback multiple times. You're over-optimizing your app. Creating an inline handler won't be an issue unless you render an ungodly amount of elements (user couldn't even use it at that point), so keep it simple. Optimize _when you need to._